# Converting bytes to Extended Precision Floating Point not accurate enough

Tags: vb.net, binary

I have some legacy files that need mined for data. The files were created by Lotus123 Release 4 for DOS. I'm trying to read the files faster by parsing the bytes rather than using Lotus to open the files. I have value records of 10 bytes each. They are [80 bit Extended Precision Floating Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision).

```
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 255, 191}))                 ' Value = -1
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {205, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 251, 191}))    ' Value = -0.1
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {10, 215, 163, 112, 61, 10, 215, 163, 248, 191}))       ' Value = -0.01
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {59, 223, 79, 141, 151, 110, 18, 131, 245, 191}))       ' Value = -0.001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {44, 101, 25, 226, 88, 23, 183, 209, 241, 191}))        ' Value = -0.0001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {35, 132, 71, 27, 71, 172, 197, 167, 238, 191}))        ' Value = -0.00001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {182, 105, 108, 175, 5, 189, 55, 134, 235, 191}))       ' Value = -0.000001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 255, 63}))                   ' Value = 1
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {205, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 251, 63}))     ' Value = 0.1
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {10, 215, 163, 112, 61, 10, 215, 163, 248, 63}))       ' Value = 0.01
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {59, 223, 79, 141, 151, 110, 18, 131, 245, 63}))       ' Value = 0.001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {44, 101, 25, 226, 88, 23, 183, 209, 241, 63}))        ' Value = 0.0001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {35, 132, 71, 27, 71, 172, 197, 167, 238, 63}))        ' Value = 0.00001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {182, 105, 108, 175, 5, 189, 55, 134, 235, 63}))       ' Value = 0.000001
Debug.Print(ConvertLongDouble80(New Byte() {188, 66, 122, 229, 213, 148, 191, 214, 231, 63}))     ' Value = 0.0000001

Function ConvertLongDouble80(ByVal TenBytes As Byte()) As Double
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

    'get 15 bit exponent; remove the first bit which is the negative sign
    Dim arrExp As Byte() = New Byte() {TenBytes(8), (TenBytes(9) << 1) >> 1}
    Dim Expo As UInt16 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(arrExp, 0)

    'flag bits
    Dim Bit63 As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16(TenBytes(7) >> 7)
    Dim Bits63_62 As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16(TenBytes(7) >> 6)

    'fractional values
    TenBytes(7) = (TenBytes(7) << 1) >> 1
    Dim Bits62_0 As UInt64 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(TenBytes, 0)
    TenBytes(7) = (TenBytes(7) << 2) >> 2
    Dim Bits61_0 As UInt64 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(TenBytes, 0)

    If Bit63 = 0 and Bits62_0 = 0 Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Const ExponentBias As Integer = 16383
        Dim isNegative As Boolean = (TenBytes(9) And (1 << 7)) <> 0
        Dim NegVal As Int16 = IIf(isNegative, -1, 1)
        Dim expVal As Double = Math.Pow(2, Expo - ExponentBias)
        Dim LBits62 As Int16 = Len(CStr(Bits62_0))
        Dim mantissa As Double = CDbl("1." & CStr(Bits62_0))
        Dim result As Double = NegVal * expVal * mantissa
        Return result       
    End If

End Function
```

> Value    -1           converts to    -1
>   Value   -0.1         converts to    -0.09708764513821
>   Value   -0.01        converts to    -0.00983011263306
>   Value   -0.001       converts to    -0.00119273528211
>   Value   -0.0001      converts to    -0.00009697388128
>   Value   -0.00001     converts to    -0.00000981589215
>   Value   -0.000001    converts to    -0.00000138095333
>   Value   1            converts to    1
>   Value   0.1          converts to    0.09708764513821
>   Value   0.01         converts to    0.00983011263306
>   Value   0.001        converts to    0.00119273528211
>   Value   0.0001       converts to    0.00009697388128
>   Value   0.00001      converts to    0.00000981589215
>   Value   0.000001     converts to    0.00000138095333
>   Value   0.0000001    converts to    0.00000009686278

What am I doing wrong. My values are not close enough. How do I fix this?

Comment: I just made a test which converts doubles to byte arrays. The result is different from what you are using as input. E.g. `BitConverter.GetBytes(0.1);`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Your input is a double. My inputs are created by Lotus 123 and are 80 bit Long Double. So yes they are different. Is it possible to still get a reasonable approximation of value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you treat the fractional part, which represents the fraction of a binary number as a whole number. I changed your function by interpreting the bits 0 to 63 as an integer number which is 2<sup>63</sup> too big. It's too big by 2<sup>63</sup> because bit 63 should be bit 0 (instead of `10110101...`, we should have `1.0110101...`, i.e., the leading `1` has to move 63 positions to the right). I then subtract 63 the the exponent to take this into account. I didn't check the logic related to the flags handling.

```
Function ConvertLongDouble80(ByVal TenBytes As Byte()) As Double
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

    ' 80-bit extended precision format
    ' --------------------------------
    ' bit 0 to 63     fraction, bytes 0 to 7
    ' bit 64 to 78    exponent (bias 16383, bytes 8 to 9)
    ' bit 79          sign                                                               /

    'get 15 bit exponent; remove the first bit which is the negative sign
    Dim arrExp As Byte() = New Byte() {TenBytes(8), (TenBytes(9) << 1) >> 1}
    Dim Expo As UInt16 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(arrExp, 0)

    'flag bits
    Dim Bit63 As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16(TenBytes(7) >> 7)
    Dim Bits63_62 As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16(TenBytes(7) >> 6)

    Dim fraction = BitConverter.ToUInt64(TenBytes, 0) ' 2 ^ 63 too big

    If Bit63 = 0 And fraction = 0 Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Const ExponentBias As Integer = 16383
        Dim isNegative As Boolean = (TenBytes(9) And (1 << 7)) <> 0
        Dim sign = If(isNegative, -1, 1)
        Dim expVal As Double = Math.Pow(2, Expo - ExponentBias - 63)
        Dim result As Double = sign * expVal * fraction
        Return result
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much. I tested it and it works perfectly.